# Combine same column from different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I'm new with R, and would like to do some basic things. 
I have three data frames with a column with the same name. In each data frame a different value is registered.
(In my real data there are more values and off course NA)

Df1

```
   Value
 A  1
 B  NA
 C  NA
 D  NA
```

Df2

```
   Value
 A  NA
 B  NA
 C  2
 D  NA
```

Df3

```
   Value
 A  NA
 B  NA
 C  NA
 D  3
```

I want to combine the three data frames so I can complete the column. So I get this:

Df

```
   Value
 A  1
 B  NA
 C  2
 D  3
```

How can I do this in R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr::coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)
Df <- data.frame(Value = coalesce(Df1$Value, Df2$Value,Df3$Value),
                 row.names = row.names(Df1))
Df
#   Value
# A     1
# B    NA
# C     2
# D     3
```

**data**

```
Df1 <- read.table(text="
Value
A  1
B  NA
C  NA
D  NA",strin=F,h=T)

Df2  <- read.table(text="
Value
A  NA
B  NA
C  2
D  NA",strin=F,h=T)

Df3  <- read.table(text="
Value
A  NA
B  NA
C  NA
D  3",strin=F,h=T)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option in `base R` is `pmin/pmax` (assuming that there is only a single non-NA element at the same location).  Place the objects in a `list` (with `mget`), and use `pmin` with `do.call`

```
do.call(pmin, c(mget(paste0("Df", 1:3)), na.rm = TRUE))
#  Value
#A     1
#B    NA
#C     2
#D     3
```

#### data

```
Df1 <- structure(list(Value = c(1L, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"))

Df2 <- structure(list(Value = c(NA, NA, 2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"))

Df3 <- structure(list(Value = c(1L, NA, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"))
```

Comment: @user195366 you can also use @akrun's solution which doesn't use an additional package and keep closer to my syntax if you prefer : `data.frame(Value = pmin(Df1$Value, Df2$Value,Df3$Value, na.rm = TRUE),
           row.names = row.names(Df1))`

Comment: your solution (@akrun) doesn't work for me as is, at least using my sample data, you're computing the min of dataframes here and it triggers the error `Error in '[.data.frame'(each, nas[, 1L]) : 
  undefined columns selected` (translated from french)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper. For me, it is working fine with the data I used.  Updated the data

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper. I also tried the data from your post.  It is working fine with me

Comment: So I assume `pmin(Df1, Df2,Df3, na.rm = TRUE)` works for you as well ? it doesn't for me with `R 3.3.1`...

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yes, it is working for me.  I am using `R 3.5.2`

Comment: I see from changes to R 3.3.2 : `pmax() and pmin() now work with (more ?) classed objects, such as "Matrix" from the Matrix package, as documented for a long time.` That might be it! https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html